# Any behavior difference between `{a: number; b: string}` and `{a: number} & {b: string}`?

Tags: typescript

Do the types below behave any differently in TypeScript?

```js
type Regular = {a: number; b: string};
type Intersection = {a: number} & {b: string};
```

I'm asking because TS doesn't automatically simplify the latter to the former (e.g. when hovering over the type in VSCode), so I was wondering if there is a behavior reason why that simplification isn't done. I assume it's more likely that TS just hasn't implemented this simplification yet, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing some subtlety about how TS works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those types *shouldn't* behave differently, as they represent the same set of values.  And for the most part they *don't* behave differently, but there are definitely situations in which two ostensibly equivalent types are treated differently by the compiler, so I can't say with confidence that they *never* behave differently.  But we know that they shouldn't.

There is a (quite longstanding) [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7705) to merge such intersections into single object types, as you suggested.  In a [related comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8228#issuecomment-218010750) the design team notes say:

> - Agree the proposed behavior is desirable
> - There are potentially some differences between `T & U` and its decomposed form?
>
>   - We can't think of any

The issue is marked as "help wanted" (so they might accept pull requests that do this) but as "effort: difficult" because they are worried about what will happen when you naively do this to self-referential types.  It's possible that it would cause the compiler to perform really badly, I guess?  Not sure if that's still a concern.

---

It's interesting to note that you can, thanks to [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types), come close to writing this type of thing yourself in the type system:

```
type RecursivelyMerge<T> = T extends Function
  ? T
  : T extends object
    ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: RecursivelyMerge<O[K]> } : never
    : T;
```

Then both `Regular` and `Intersection` become the same type:

```
type MergedRegular = RecursivelyMerge<Regular>; // {a: number; b: string}
type MergedIntersection = RecursivelyMerge<Intersection>; // {a: number; b: string}
```

And you can do nested types too:

```
type Nested = RecursivelyMerge<
  { a: { b: { c: { d: string } } } } & { a: { b: { c: { e: number } } } }
>; 
// type Nested = { a: { b: { c: {d: string; e: number } } } }
```

and even self-referential types seem to be no problem (except that they are displayed strangely):

```
type Tree = { node: Tree[] };
type ExplodedTree = RecursivelyMerge<Tree>; 
// type ExplodedTree = { node: ...[]; } // hmm, weird
declare const t: ExplodedTree;
t.node[2].node[10].node[42].node // works fine though
```

---

So my guess is that someone sufficiently motivated could write up some code to have this happen automatically in the compiler when intersections of anonymous types show up, with enough of a test suite to prove that recursive types don't bog things down, and it could possibly, maybe end up in the language.  Well, as long as the performance penalty in general is very low.  That's just a guess though.

Oh well, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIBsQFkJkBzCAHgBUA+KAXigqggA9gIA7AE1SgDFF28YOgD27ALAAoKFAD8DKTIBcDJqw7coIgEYArBMEUy5qlmy4907AGZEoAeRMBvKAG0A0lCtQA1hBAi1g4AuipwSGhYuAREpGT2HsE0AL5QKuwQ2MhGygwA3FJSoJCwEMSIOACGyHRQLpXpiAC22kR5UNoqqMDIVsRQyQWSxdAAkuxsaAai7LX1jS12qQBkdR1dPX0DQ0Xg0IQkEJxw5VU19OEoGNh4B3EnFdVU7QD0L3UNUOzNrcjtnVBur12MRkrsSncjuNJqhpmJapdIjcYocyNCiLChDNnlA3h8Fr9-htgaDCsM9lAAHIQbpHBEIK5RW6xchGeZrAEueAqFycYlbVKCgZQVbslycqDctYQAlLYWCqTPKR4kZUmlsThzKCfcU8yU8vmAzYg9oyr4-OVCsGScHQCjICDQegudgiThm+2O1zBba2qAAUWYYBwbqOnqdpQi12ikMoDogOOV71VgeDoc44a1rvdKgAdPnve1UniABZNJoAGigAHcIOhkJwpO74GdoPAxN0oMAVKmQ+6M-GhsBc9mIK4AEzBEeh1wARgADFPR64ACyT6fu3HvasiZA+HjWKzQYAlkSIYglslAA)

Comment: There are instances where an intersection behaves differently from a unified type, especially with weaker types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGB+AXMqAnCAjgK4CW+AJtgHZEC2ARhLgL4A0UA9tgM7C4lUA5lGYBYAFChIUAEIIcGbEmYioAMhxcovfkLGTw0GQFUqJAGYkI5eSkXI2UTjz4DB+iQBsIwKPUxyiHZKjloARGEiXj5omHCI9ADcEhYAFKgAdKgAlMgSTk6ZmfjEZNZQAPQVUDQMTH5Evvionp4gUERU5BCWVOUSHuLevvREAaYWVjZBsQ7s4ZH6qPKjldVMuBy4EhJAA